# Retrieve data from Redis and display them on the frontend

Tags: angularjs, node.js, redis, socket.io, node-redis

I push and retrieve the data from the Redis list in the NodeJS(Express), but I cannot send them and display on the frontend (Angular).

I push the message with the lpush method and retrieve with lrange and I want to send these data to the frontend (with express -> app.get{}). On the frontend I use Angular with [angular-socket-io factory](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-socket-io).

Please take a look at the server.js file bellow.

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static('../app/'));
app.use('/bower_components', express.static('../bower_components/'));

var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

var redis = require('redis')
var redisClient = redis.createClient();

/**
 *  Store a message in redis
 *
 *  @function storeMessage
 *  @param {String} name
 *  @param {Object} data
 */

function storeMessage (name, data) {
    var message = JSON.stringify({name:name, data:data});

    // store up to 10 messages
    redisClient.lpush('messages', message, function(error) {
        if (error) throw error;
        redisClient.ltrim('messages', 0, 10);
    });
};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {

    /**
     *  When users join, set their nickname and broadcast they are here
     *  Add the user to redis
     */

    redisClient.lrange('messages', 0, -1, function( error, messages) {
        messages = messages.reverse();

        messages.forEach(function(message) {
            message = JSON.parse(message);
            client.emit('messages',message.name + ' : ' + message.data);
        });
    });
});

//!!TROUBLE HERE?? -> send data to the frontend
app.get('/messages', function (err, res) {
    'use strict';

    messages.forEach(function(res) {
        client.emit("messages", res.name + ": " + res.data);
    });
    res.send(messages);
});

server.listen(3000, function () {
    'use strict';
});
```

Comment: Give more info. do you get an error? Do you use AJAX to make the get request?

Comment: Yes, I got an error "GET http://192.168.1.64:3000/messages(Not Found)", but I solved the problem. I put lrange method in the app.get {} and on the frontend (angular), I got the data with $http service. Now I have data in JSON format (in console), but I cannot display them with ng-repeat. Please take a look at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29y61wtg/2/)

Comment: When I've stored the data to the redis list, I've used JSON.stringify and in output from list I got in console data with this format ["[{"name":"Msg1 ","desc":"desc Msg1"},{"name":…Msg3"},{"name":"Msg4","desc":"desc Msg4"}]"]. I tried with .parse, but I got an error :/